# Create a raster data file from text

Tags: python, raster, gdal, text

I have a text dataset that displays the depth of seabed with the heading longitude, latitude, and average_depth. I am trying to create a raster file from this data. I have tried converting it to a point shapefile in ArcGIS and then to a raster from this shapefile using the point to raster tool but the tool seems to have given up half way resulting in the following raster:

The image is displaying 0 values as black in the image but this is not the case in the actual data as I have checked the data values and they do not contain zero values.

[image]

I have tried to apply `gdal.Grid` in the following code:

```py
import gdal
import os

save_file_raw = r"D:\Documents\PhD\GIS\High_Res_Bathy\CV16_CelticSeaIreland_14m\wexford_highRes.txt"

save_file = save_file_raw.replace('\\', '/')

save_file_folder_raw = r"D:\Documents\PhD\GIS\High_Res_Bathy\CV16_CelticSeaIreland_14m"

save_file_folder = save_file_folder_raw.replace("\\", "/")

print(os.listdir(save_file_folder))

def find_txt_filenames(path_to_dir, suffix = r".txt"):
    filenames = os.listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(suffix)]
txtfiles = find_txt_filenames(save_file_folder)
print(txtfiles)

for fn in txtfiles:
    vrt_fn = save_file.replace(".txt", ".vrt")
    lyr_name = save_file.replace(".txt", "")
    output_tif =  save_file.replace(".txt", ".tiff")
    with open(vrt_fn, "w") as fn_vrt:
        fn_vrt.write("<OGRVRTDataSource>\n")
        fn_vrt.write('\t<OGRVRTLayer name="%s">\n' % lyr_name)
        fn_vrt.write('\t\t<SrcDataSource>%s</SrcDataSource>\n' % save_file)
        fn_vrt.write('\t\t<GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>\n')
        fn_vrt.write('\t\t<GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude" z="Depth_Average"/>\n')
        fn_vrt.write('\t</OGRVRTLayer>\n')
        fn_vrt.write('</OGRVRTDataSource>\n')

output = gdal.Grid(output_tif,'name.vrt')
```

This has returned the following error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9ab798d8d138> in <module>
     32         fn_vrt.write('</OGRVRTDataSource>\n')
     33 
---> 34 output = gdal.Grid(output_tif,'name.vrt')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py in Grid(destName, srcDS, **kwargs)
   1045         srcDS = OpenEx(srcDS, gdalconst.OF_VECTOR)
   1046 
-> 1047     return GridInternal(destName, srcDS, opts, callback, callback_data)
   1048 
   1049 def RasterizeOptions(options=None, format=None,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py in GridInternal(*args)
   3360 def GridInternal(*args):
   3361     """GridInternal(char const * dest, Dataset dataset, GDALGridOptions options, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None) -> Dataset"""
-> 3362     return _gdal.GridInternal(*args)
   3363 class GDALRasterizeOptions(object):
   3364     """Proxy of C++ GDALRasterizeOptions class."""

ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.
```

I'm pretty new to the Python game so I am sorry if I have not provided all the relevant info in the first round.

EDIT:

Here is first part of the dataset, the columns that I wish to use in the raster are Longitude, Latitude and Depth_Average:

[image]

Here is an example of the text file, I could not upload the full thing because it is approx 1.5 Gb in size:

```
Longitude,Latitude,Depth_Average
-6.3551416,52.07466115,61.46
-6.35501139,52.07466115,61.76
-6.35579264,52.07453094,59.94
-6.35566244,52.07453094,60.21
-6.35553223,52.07453094,60.1
-6.35540202,52.07453094,60.28
-6.35527181,52.07453094,60.78
-6.3551416,52.07453094,61.28
-6.35501139,52.07453094,61.54
-6.35488119,52.07453094,61.05
-6.35631348,52.07440073,58.22
-6.35618327,52.07440073,58.49
-6.35605306,52.07440073,58.94
-6.35592285,52.07440073,59.42
-6.35579264,52.07440073,59.71
-6.35566244,52.07440073,60.01
-6.35553223,52.07440073,60.38
-6.35540202,52.07440073,60.65
-6.35527181,52.07440073,60.54
-6.3551416,52.07440073,60.86
-6.35501139,52.07440073,61.01
-6.35488119,52.07440073,61.08
-6.35696452,52.07427052,55.95
-6.35683431,52.07427052,55.33
-6.3567041,52.07427052,56.01
-6.35657389,52.07427052,56.83
-6.35644369,52.07427052,57.29
-6.35631348,52.07427052,57.69
-6.35618327,52.07427052,58.15
-6.35605306,52.07427052,58.56
-6.35592285,52.07427052,58.98
-6.35579264,52.07427052,59.4
-6.35566244,52.07427052,59.67
-6.35553223,52.07427052,60.1
-6.35540202,52.07427052,60.5
-6.35527181,52.07427052,60.74
-6.3551416,52.07427052,61.01
-6.35501139,52.07427052,61.33
-6.35488119,52.07427052,61.62
-6.35475098,52.07427052,61.76
-6.35761556,52.07414031,60.05
-6.35748535,52.07414031,59.65
-6.35735514,52.07414031,58.74
-6.35722494,52.07414031,57.51
-6.35709473,52.07414031,55.56
-6.35696452,52.07414031,56.1
-6.35683431,52.07414031,55.78
-6.3567041,52.07414031,55.58
-6.35657389,52.07414031,56.19
-6.35644369,52.07414031,56.9
-6.35631348,52.07414031,57.37
-6.35618327,52.07414031,57.72
-6.35605306,52.07414031,58.2
-6.35592285,52.07414031,58.46
-6.35579264,52.07414031,58.92
-6.35566244,52.07414031,59.35
-6.35553223,52.07414031,59.68
-6.35540202,52.07414031,60.11
-6.35527181,52.07414031,60.51
-6.3551416,52.07414031,60.74
-6.35501139,52.07414031,61.01
-6.35488119,52.07414031,61.53
-6.35475098,52.07414031,61.85
-6.35800618,52.07401011,61.38
-6.35787598,52.07401011,61.22
-6.35774577,52.07401011,60.86
-6.35761556,52.07401011,60.23
-6.35748535,52.07401011,60.03
-6.35735514,52.07401011,59.44
-6.35722494,52.07401011,58.57
-6.35709473,52.07401011,57.28
-6.35696452,52.07401011,55.44
-6.35683431,52.07401011,55.99
-6.3567041,52.07401011,55.72
-6.35657389,52.07401011,55.88
-6.35644369,52.07401011,56.3
-6.35631348,52.07401011,56.67
-6.35618327,52.07401011,57.08
-6.35605306,52.07401011,57.65
-6.35592285,52.07401011,58.1
-6.35579264,52.07401011,58.63
-6.35566244,52.07401011,59.03
-6.35553223,52.07401011,59.23
-6.35540202,52.07401011,59.62
-6.35527181,52.07401011,60.18
-6.3551416,52.07401011,60.61
-6.35501139,52.07401011,60.83
-6.35488119,52.07401011,61.21
-6.35475098,52.07401011,61.56
-6.35462077,52.07401011,61.61
-6.35852702,52.0738799,61.29
-6.35839681,52.0738799,60.77
-6.3582666,52.0738799,60.55
-6.35813639,52.0738799,61.04
-6.35800618,52.0738799,61.25
-6.35787598,52.0738799,61.27
-6.35774577,52.0738799,61.11
-6.35761556,52.0738799,60.78
-6.35748535,52.0738799,60.28
-6.35735514,52.0738799,59.99
-6.35722494,52.0738799,59.29
-6.35709473,52.0738799,58.39
-6.35696452,52.0738799,56.81
-6.35683431,52.0738799,55.01
-6.3567041,52.0738799,54.86
-6.35657389,52.0738799,55.63
-6.35644369,52.0738799,56.4
-6.35631348,52.0738799,56.95
-6.35618327,52.0738799,57.09
-6.35605306,52.0738799,57.12
-6.35592285,52.0738799,57.51
-6.35579264,52.0738799,58.25
-6.35566244,52.0738799,58.78
-6.35553223,52.0738799,59.12
-6.35540202,52.0738799,59.35
-6.35527181,52.0738799,59.53
-6.3551416,52.0738799,60.28
-6.35501139,52.0738799,60.71
-6.35488119,52.0738799,60.95
-6.35475098,52.0738799,61.31
-6.35462077,52.0738799,61.45
-6.35449056,52.0738799,61.53
-6.35904785,52.07374969,60.96
-6.35891764,52.07374969,60.82
-6.35878743,52.07374969,60.97
-6.35865723,52.07374969,61.24
-6.35852702,52.07374969,61.28
-6.35839681,52.07374969,61.26
-6.3582666,52.07374969,60.89
-6.35813639,52.07374969,60.67
-6.35800618,52.07374969,60.81
-6.35787598,52.07374969,60.79
-6.35774577,52.07374969,61.25
-6.35761556,52.07374969,61.23
-6.35748535,52.07374969,60.78
-6.35735514,52.07374969,60.26
-6.35722494,52.07374969,59.94
-6.35709473,52.07374969,59.28
-6.35696452,52.07374969,58.58
-6.35683431,52.07374969,57.44
-6.3567041,52.07374969,55.67
-6.35657389,52.07374969,54.41
-6.35644369,52.07374969,55.31
-6.35631348,52.07374969,56.28
-6.35618327,52.07374969,57.19
-6.35605306,52.07374969,57.44
-6.35592285,52.07374969,57.4
-6.35579264,52.07374969,57.58
-6.35566244,52.07374969,58.34
-6.35553223,52.07374969,58.92
-6.35540202,52.07374969,59.39
-6.35527181,52.07374969,59.69
-6.3551416,52.07374969,59.77
-6.35501139,52.07374969,59.96
-6.35488119,52.07374969,60.44
-6.35475098,52.07374969,60.9
-6.35462077,52.07374969,61.4
-6.35449056,52.07374969,61.61
-6.3598291,52.07361948,60.95
-6.35956868,52.07361948,59.8
-6.35943848,52.07361948,58.62
-6.35930827,52.07361948,59.81
-6.35917806,52.07361948,60.1
-6.35904785,52.07361948,60.66
-6.35891764,52.07361948,60.65
-6.35878743,52.07361948,60.96
-6.35865723,52.07361948,61.01
-6.35852702,52.07361948,61.17
-6.35839681,52.07361948,61.2
-6.3582666,52.07361948,61.3
-6.35813639,52.07361948,61.06
-6.35800618,52.07361948,60.98
-6.35787598,52.07361948,60.38
-6.35774577,52.07361948,60.7
-6.35761556,52.07361948,61.27
-6.35748535,52.07361948,61.18
-6.35735514,52.07361948,60.94
-6.35722494,52.07361948,60.62
-6.35709473,52.07361948,60.17
-6.35696452,52.07361948,59.44
-6.35683431,52.07361948,58.58
-6.3567041,52.07361948,57.87
-6.35657389,52.07361948,56.76
-6.35644369,52.07361948,54.76
-6.35631348,52.07361948,54.84
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE! Can you paste a sample of the text file in your question?

Comment: Hey Marcelo, many thanks for the warm welcome, I have added the first 5 rows, hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: Hi, I have added part of the data, couldn't upload all of it the file is quite large.